# Проблемы с парсингом сайта на c#

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Log
{
    static class WebScraper
    {
        public static string url = @"https://market.yandex.ru/product--noutbuk-asus-tuf-gaming-a15-fa507/1761002643?glfilter=14871214%3A14896295_101807967921&glfilter=14806501%3A36763198_101807967921&glfilter=16499888%3A37513490_101807967921&glfilter=24892510%3A24892630_101807967921&glfilter=36036031%3A36427132_101807967921&glfilter=45123612%3A50195424_101821342216&glfilter=37699290%3A39025873_101807967921&glfilter=34812830%3A36106120_101807967921&glfilter=45131230%3A50216695_101807967921&cpa=1&cpc=YNcHNOrJq9nDg1preg3lwjQO-Nv3BpIMZUYmuWqk0eduOAfHS1B-JDpDAesLSMaDlz42b3nWF8ZtYSbasF3Dh3QKewHoCHq1HX6I51AewOgoxtWhgmy0DFF8qEb8vmmvX_26lnqsYJYzh96isgi3IbCIzS25xysbLjGu2FyOZW-mewZIrmDJSoq1TJtUJLTdPePYmaaHanaW2fgDxZ_ILijdrpJHNkMJfTa8I91g6ZBDTqRSr6fA3KMykxzM78kODx3jszg8r-A%2C&rs=eJwdUC2LQlEUvM9N4i8QXLibDaLNL3huEmSLGBVeEv-D5YIKBjHZLDfLEzRs8QOfQcQmiGFB8OEiNoOgYvPOlGGYOWfm3JtQHytLiGrWoFNKG_TOGYP2aWpQ7VMG_S4U7wZXuNBtRb6ELtpAHZlh_odbFyj-CNyZ0I3C1T0qe3BZAIoieu0v5jThyjXnf4GqnETOi_eMgc4dvX59Ab6BK-PcrbBxgEw7z8wn9SC4bAB1hjdYdGPo0h2-t8WuB3t3fOmQbp-9W_6AS_7HyQO2nH_eI6l_zqF_szHA_BAnNdPCTD7yfxRncuDelS219BvXhIgd&sku=101821342216&do-waremd5=BerPo08VsB0nxtzZQ7E-Jg&nid=42287971";

        public static string GetPage(string url)
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

            var element = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@class='LNoB0']").InnerHtml;

            return element;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = WebScraper.GetPage(WebScraper.url);
            Console.WriteLine(data);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Почему данный код выдает ошибку? Мне хотя бы получить html того xpath, которого я записал.
(не реклама ноутбука)

Comment: собачка точно там нужна ? `string url = @"ht....`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818459/c-sharp-html-agility-pack-selectsinglenode `"//input[@class='LNoB0']"` класс правильный взяли ?

Comment: А какая ошибка, мы должны гадать, да? Предположу, что `NullReferenceException`, ибо `LNoB0` похоже на случайное значение, чтоб сайт трудней парсился. Теперь по порядку: 1. `new HtmlWeb();` - не советую, лучше создайте `HttpClient`, который будет в едином экземпляре для всего вашего проекта, получите куда больше контроля, чем обертка над ним в виде `HtmlWeb` (который также должен быть 1). 2.  Как и говорил выше, `LNoB0` - это рандомное значение, видите такое, значит сразу что-то не то. 3. `.InnerHtml` у `NULL` (объект не найден) == ошибка. 4. Вы вообще уверены, что ссылка дает вам данные?

Comment: Изучил сайт. Как и думал, он не дает вам данных, ибо если вы программно получите данные с сайта, то сайт выдаст [капчу](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQhgJ.png), ибо он не находит у вас признаки "человечности" (нет JS как минимум). Чтоб получать нужные данные, вам надо разобрать всю портянку Cookie, которые сайт вам ставит при первом посещении, часть из них, это `is_gdpr_b` и `spravka`, вроде они отвечают (особенно последний) за это все. НО, сайт требует не одну из, а их все, которые он время от времени проверяет. Разберетесь как получить их, будет вам парсинг, ну а нет - используйте браузер.

Comment: Благодарю, я вас услышал